# Java Android Studio Interface Builder not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, interface

Here is [a gyazo](https://gyazo.com/9521365ed3dce9c0b13c18afde400204) because I don't know what's going on.

Basically it won't show up on the iphone, I'm currently watching a tutorial on YT and it worked for him. Any help appreciated!

One more thing is that the Hello world that's supposed to appear when you start the application won't show up either. Is there a setting or something?

Comment: Because you are using Constrained layout, can you post your xml code

Comment: Here sorry for the late reply <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: Add your `ativity_main.xml` not `styles.xml` by editing your question.